# how can I run a sandboxed OS X app without sandboxing?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

I have an app which runs using sandboxing. How can I run it without sandboxing? Suppose I can't just recompile the app with sandboxing off.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works:

```
$ ditto MySandboxedApp.app MySandboxedApp.backup.app
$ codesign -f -s- MySandboxedApp.app
```

Note the extra minus in "-s-".

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that all do conceptually the same thing - make `sandbox_init` a no-op. For example you can use `gdb` for this, set breakpoint on `sandbox_init` and return from the function right away. Or you could preload a library containing an empty `sandbox_init` with `DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1 DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=foo.dylib` where `foo.dylib` just contains `int sandbox_init() { return 0; }`.

Note that sandboxing is voluntary and if you run an app outside a sandbox as designed you're making your system more vulnerable.

Comment: I tried putting a breakpoint on sandbox_init and it wasn't hit. Thoughts?

Comment: I guess we are talking about different things then - I was talking about explicit sandboxing (see `man sandbox`) as used by OS X, but I suppose you're talking about the app store sandboxing which anentirely different specification.